# Devel themer not working (cant see the checkbox)

Tags: theming

I want to see from where different elements are coming from. [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module does this, but I cannot see the checkbox in the lower left of  the page. It was working earlier but it isnt now, i am using drupal 7.

Anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting Javascript Aggregation in performance options solved the problem for me.  Found the solution on this thread - http://drupal.org/node/1790402

Answer (score 2):

1. Check to see if the module is still enabled.
2. Clear the cache.
3. Check to see if the currently logged-in user has appropriate permissions to see devel_themer info.

It's likely #3.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that devel_themer module is not compatible with the latest version of simplehtmldom API.

On the [drupal devel_themer project page](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is announced:

**NOTE**:
Currently, Theme Developer does not work with the latest version of
simplehtmldom API. You must use simplehtml API version 7.x-1.12 if you want Theme Developer to function properly.

You can download version 7.x-1.12 on the [drupal simplehtmldom API project page](https://drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this [link](https://www.koumbit.org/en/content/what-do-when-devel-and-devel-themer-arent-printing-any-messages-google-chrome) works for me.

It's because the logo path is not found and there are error script in my js.